# Download Web Page Source Code to Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, html

I am trying to have web page source code for yahoo.com downloaded into my excel sheet.

I didn't manage to build a code. My code (mentioned below) is downloading webpage text NOT source:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;https://www.yahoo.com/?p=us" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "?p=us"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Comment: Share your code! It's OK that it doesnt build... That's what this site is for.

Answer (score 0):

Use Microsoft's XML functionality

Activate **Microsoft XML, v3.0** (or 6 if you're in 2010 and upwards) in  Tools/References in the VBA editor, then start your code like this:

```
    Dim oXML As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    Dim xURL As String
    Dim uTxt As String

    xURL = "https://www.yahoo.com/?p=us"

    oXML.Open "GET", xURL, False
    oXML.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml" 
    oXML.send

    uTxt = oXML.responseText

    Codesplit = Split(uTxt, Chr(13))
```

You can then either write the lines to a sheet line by line or, much faster, feed the split values into an array and send that to the sheet in one go.

I use it to parse the HTML in memory and download just the data I want from the web page. HTH